# Eliminate excessive white space and new lines in C# code

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015

I'm using Visual Studio 2015.  The developer before me must have used a tool to introduce huge amounts of white space into his code.  Also statements are spread across many lines when they really should be on one line.

Here's a sample:

```
var requestCustomer = new GetCustomersByIdentifierRequest
{
    Metadata =
                                  new CustomerSearchRetrieveReference
                                  .RequestMetadata
                                  {
                                      SecurityAction
                                              = "Get",
                                      UserId =
                                              "WebService"
                                  },
    Params =
                                  new GetCustomersByIdentifierParams
                                  {
                                      EffectiveAsOf
                                              =
                                              DateTime
                                              .Today,
                                      Identifiers
                                              =
                                              resultSearch
                                              .Select
                                              (
                                                  x
                                                  =>
                                                  x
                                                      .CustomerUd)
                                              .ToList
                                              (
                                                  )
                                  }
};
```

It's really quite excessive.  Is there some command or tool I can use to auto-format or reformat this code and at least get expressions and basic assignments onto single lines?  Even if it just gets me closer, that would be a great help.  It's quite tedious to do it manually.

I have tried using Ctrl+K,F but it doesn't change the code at all.

Please, something simple and preferably built-in.  I'm trying not to lose too much time on this.

Comment: That online tool is really cool, however the code is still 33 lines, so not too much progress.  But Minify works brilliantly!  You should post an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<kbd>Ctrl+K</kbd> + <kbd>Ctrl+D</kbd> is limited to formatting pure white space, and won't remove unnecessary lines in a document. For example:

```
SomeMethod(     );
```

Will format to `SomeMethod();`

However:

```
SomeMethod(


);
```

Will remain the same.

As far as I know, there is nothing built in Visual Studio 2010, 2013 or 2015 that would do this. I did find an [online tool](http://codebeautify.org/csharpviewer) that was very close to achieving what it is you're after.

Your code sample of:

```
var requestCustomer = new GetCustomersByIdentifierRequest
{
Metadata =
                              new CustomerSearchRetrieveReference
                              .RequestMetadata
                              {
                                  SecurityAction
                                          = "Get",
                                  UserId =
                                          "WebService"
                              },
Params =
                              new GetCustomersByIdentifierParams
                              {
                                  EffectiveAsOf
                                          =
                                          DateTime
                                          .Today,
                                  Identifiers
                                          =
                                          resultSearch
                                          .Select
                                          (
                                              x
                                              =>
                                              x
                                                  .CustomerUd)
                                          .ToList
                                          (
                                              )
                              }
};
```

Was formatted to this result:

```
var requestCustomer = new GetCustomersByIdentifierRequest {
 Metadata =
  new CustomerSearchRetrieveReference
  .RequestMetadata {
   SecurityAction
    = "Get",
    UserId =
    "WebService"
  },
  Params =
  new GetCustomersByIdentifierParams {
   EffectiveAsOf
    =
    DateTime
    .Today,
    Identifiers =
    resultSearch
    .Select(
     x =>
     x
     .CustomerUd)
    .ToList()
  }
};
```

It's not perfect, but it does make the code far more sane, and wouldn't be incredibly time-consuming to get it where you'd like it to be manually. It may enable <kbd>Ctrl+K</kbd> + <kbd>Ctrl+D</kbd> to handle some of the load too.

Comment: The online tool in the link you provided using the "Minify" option rather than the "Beautify" option, and giving it pieces of code rather than huge chunks works brilliantly. In some situations it looks like it just makes it all one long line, but when I pasted into VS, it was great.

Answer (score 3):

I use 'Format Document'.
Menu: Edit > Advanced > Format Document
Shortcut: <kbd>Ctrl+E</kbd> + <kbd>Ctrl+D</kbd>

It uses the formatting configuration from Tools > Options > Text Editor > C# > Formatting

Comment: Are you sure this works? In my experience this only fixes indentation and won't bring parenthesis together if there's white space, for example.

Comment: This is not the correct shortcut for Format Document in VS2015.  It's Ctrl+K,D, and I did mention I already tried that.  It makes no change.

Comment: @Sandra: If you set up VS2015 with C# default settings, it's both. Don't ask me why...

Comment: @DrewKennedy: It don't removes empty lines. But the shown code seems to have only a indentation problem. If there __are__ empty lines, this function will not do the job, that's right.